# Display child post on parent post page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Our current website is using custom posts with parent/child posts.
When viewing a (parent) post, a plugin is used to pull its child posts and those are displayed in a tab on the page.

We are using a new version of that custom theme on several websites now and are no longer using parent/child relationship. Instead we have metaboxes in our custom posts types and all additional information can be filed right there.

I wanted to update this particular website with the latest version of the theme, but since it's using parent/child relationship I wanted to add a few lines of code to the theme in order to achieve the same result and keep the old posts the way they are instead of modifying them all.

Here's what I want to do : I want a very simple way to display all child post (in order) on a parent post page.

I've found a few ideas here and there but none seems to be working so far. (Here's one for example : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/ as well as this one https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/153042/how-to-display-list-of-child-pages-with-parent-in-wordpress). I don't know if it has to do with the fact that i'm using post rather than pages.

I don't want a list of the child post but rather display the content of those directly. Was thinking the best way to achieve this might be to create a function to retrieve the child post and then echoing the result in the template. That way without having to change our theme it could work with our different website.

**EDIT :**

So far here's what i've tried within single.php :

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
 ));
while($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_content(); //Outputs child's content as it is
}
wp_reset_query();`
```

---

I then changed the code to :

```
$new_args = array(
'order'          => 'ASC',
'post_parent'    => get_the_ID()
);
$new_query = new WP_Query( $new_args);
if ($new_query->have_posts() ) {
    while($new_query->have_posts() ) {
        $new_query->the_post();
            the_content();
    }
wp_reset_query();
}
```

---

and then since it didn't work either i've changed it to :

```
$children = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID()) );
foreach ( $children as $children_id => $children ) {
    the_title();
    the_content();
}
```

The latest seems to be able to return some results, it "knows" that the current post has children in it but i'm displaying the title and content of the current post. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be using `the_content()` in here.

Comment: You probably should use WP_Query with metaquery as an additional param to select posts with certain metadata (If I've understood you correct you store this parentchild logic in metaboxes right now, is it true?).

We can't help you unless you will show us some code / metabox structure or custom post structure at least

Comment: Actually really not trying to have the content being displayed in the metaboxes. All i'm looking for is a simple way to display child post content on the parent post page. I might have given a little too much information with the metaboxes which makes it a bit confusing. I'm using the default post type but i've added a bit of customization to it so it might no be considered custom post type per say. I just want the "normal" content from the child post on the parent post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, try something like this inside your post template within the loop. It should help you to output child posts inside particular post.
<?php
/*Somwhere in the loop*/

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'posts_per_page' => 3, //shows only 3 children. If you want to show all of them, comment this line
    ));
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        /*Output the child markup here*/
        the_content(); //Outputs child's content as it is
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

UPDATED:
Ok, you can try to use post_parent__in & array of IDs, this should work too.
<?php
/*Somwhere in the loop*/

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_parent__in' => array(get_the_ID()),
        'posts_per_page' => 3, //shows only 3 children. If you want to show all of them, comment this line
    ));
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        /*Output the child markup here*/
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

If not, here is the way to output contents of the posts you got using get_children function. This should probably work too

```
<?php
    $children = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID()) );
    foreach ( $children as $children_id => $child ) {
        echo $child->post_title;
        echo str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;',apply_filters( 'the_content', $child->post_content )); //mimic the_content() filters
        //echo $child->post_content; // if you do not need to filter the content;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried using your code within the loop but it's not returning anything even if I know this post has a child.

Comment: Are you using it within single.php ? It's often used to output single posts. Could you show me your code?

Comment: I've edited the original post to display the code i've tried. I'm pretty sure it's something stupid at this point but I can't seem to get it work. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Great last one did it for me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Fetch only one level child pages of a parent page */    
         $pages = get_pages(
         array (
                  'parent'  => 'parent_id', 
                  'post_type  => 'page', 
                  'post_status'  => 'publish',
                );
                
         $ids = wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' );
 /* Return page IDs in array format */
 /* You can retrieve "post_title", "guid", "post_name" instead of "ID"

/* Fetch all child pages of a parent page*/    
$pages = get_pages(
         array (
         'parent'  => '-1',
         'child_of' => 'parent_id', /* Return child of child for current page id */
         'post_type  => 'page',
         'post_status'  => 'publish',
          );
         $ids = wp_list_pluck( $pages, 'ID' );
/* Return page IDs in array format */
/* You can retrieve "post_title", "guid", "post_name" instead of "ID" */
```