# Retrieve data in loop from database issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code for insert data into DB.

```
if (isset($_POST['file_edit_note']) && isset($_POST['file_notes']) && !empty($_POST['file_edit_note'])) {
    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['ID'] = $_POST['file_edit_note'];
    $my_post['post_content'] = $_POST['file_notes'];
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'posts', array(
   "post_content" => $_POST['file_notes'],
   "post_parent" => $_POST['file_edit_note']),array( '%s'), array('%d'));
    wp_redirect(get_permalink() . '?upd=1');
}
```

And,here the post ID is the parent. I try to get the post id and insert into the post_parent column on the child row. This part is working.

[image]

now i tried to retrieve the data in a loop.because when I open the parent in front end all the child comes from the parent.

```
 <?php echo !empty($file->post_content)?$file->post_content:'Content not found.'; ?>
```

I am new to PHP. Please give me any Suggestions.

Comment: What query do you use to retrieve the data? What do you get, and what is the expected result?

Comment: Retrieve query :  <?php echo !empty($file->post_content)?$file->post_content:'Content not found.'; ?>

Comment: I get only the parent content

Comment: What id do you use to load $file?

Comment: the expected result is getting all the content. which is having the parent id on post_parent column

Comment: $file using parent ID

Comment: Is this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705922/display-child-post-on-parent-post-page-in-wordpress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160986/discussion-between-user8911773-and-user4035).